# Salesforce Bulk API - "missing a mapping for the external id field" error

Tags: salesforce

I'm starting a bulk API job and passing a spec file. Here is the job.txt file I'm using to create the job:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jobInfo xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
    <operation>upsert</operation>
    <object>Contact</object>
    <externalIdFieldName>Unique_Email__c</externalIdFieldName>
    <contentType>CSV</contentType>
</jobInfo>
```

Then, I'm posting a spec file as follows:

```
Salesforce Field,Csv Header,Value,Hint
Unique_Email__c,email1,,
Name,Full Name,,
```

And I get the error "Transformation specification is missing a mapping for the external id field" but that's very strange because the Unique_Email__c is actually there. What's going on?

Comment: The CSV to be posted is not very clear, can you reformat it a lillte bit more, by the way from where are you consuming th bulk api?